# How to check if the string ends with 8 characters in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Im trying to check if the string "m" starts with "https://pastebin.com" and ends with 8 letters, but i really don't know how.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Paste URL:");
string m = Console.ReadLine();
if (m.StartsWith("https://pastebin.com/") && m.EndsWith($"8 letters"))
{
    Console.Write(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw/" + m.Remove(0, 21)));
}
```

Comment: Do you know what regular expressions are? That would be one possible way to solve this.

Comment: Nope, could you tell me?

Answer (score 3):

```
string checkStr = "https://pastebin.com/blabla1abcdergx";
string pattern= "https://pastebin.com/.*[a-zA-Z]{8}$";

if (new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(checkStr))
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.Substring` to extract the last 8 characters and use LINQ's `All()` method to test if they're all letters:

```
if(m.StartsWith("https://pastebin.com") && m.Substring(m.Length - 8).All(char.IsLetter)){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because char code independent. Just need to check the length in case of a different domain to not get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException with SubString. Also using MoreLINQ there is TakeLast (or just with Linq, the string can be Reverse to use Take).

Comment: @OlivierRogier `m.StartsWith(stringLongerThan8chars)` acts as an indirect bounds check here :-)

Comment: @MathiasRJessen In fact there is no problem until there is `https://...` or `http://a...`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an url, i would use the right tool so neither string methods nor regex but `Uri`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://Pastebin.com/abcdefgh");
bool isHttps = uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
bool isPastebin =  uri.Host.Equals("pastebin.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
string path = uri.LocalPath.Trim('/'); 
bool remaining8Letters = path.Length == 8 && path.All(char.IsLetter);
```

or including url-parameters

```
string pathWithQuery = uri.PathAndQuery.Trim('/');
```